# How can I print everything before match?

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to use awk match() and substr to print everything before the match occurs. I am using  awk in a bash script to pull out a string from a file name, and have tried the following:

```
awk 'match($0,".S") {print substr($0, RSTART+1, 3)}'
```

This gives me 3 chars, *S* plus the 2 following it.

But, I want is to print everything before the match.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Just a minor rearrangement:

```
awk 'match($0, "\.S") {print substr($0, 1, RSTART + 3)}'
```

This tells AWK to print starting from the first character through the "S" and the next two characters.

To get the same result from `sed`:

Simple version (".S" can only appear once:

```
sed 's/\(.*\.S..\).*/\1/'
```

If ".S" can appear more than once, this version gives the same result as the AWK version (only the first ".S" and its two following characters are kept):

```
sed 's/\.S../&\n/; s/\n.*//'
```

**Edit:**

```
perl -nle 'print "$`$&" if /\.S../'
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
awk '{i = index($0, ".S"); if (i>0) print substr($0, 0, i+5)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use:

```
sed 's/.S.*//'
```

Comment: That doesn't give the output the OP is looking for.

Comment: AFAIU the OP wants a filename which is followed by some char and capital S, e.g. `echo filename:S:othertext:morecapital.S | sed 's/.S.*//'` extracts the filename.

Comment: I interpret that he wants to include the character (or literal dot) and the "S" and the next two characters as well as the initial string. The key word in the question for me is "also".